# Reset Password testing with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

i am using rails and want to write a test for password reset in Rspec. i am quite new to testing.
this is what i have done so far:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UsersController, type: :controller do

describe 'post #reset_password' do
let(:user) { create(:user) }

context "reset password" do  
  def do_request
    patch :update_password
  end

  before { do_request }
  it { expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count(1) } 
   end
  end
end
```

every time i run this it gives ma an syntax error in 
`"it { expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count(1) } "`.
i want to check whether the email successfully sent of not and if the user have key in the email.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) you miss `)` at last here so got syntax error

```
it { expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count(1) }
```

to

```
it { expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count(1)) }
```

2)
 If you want to check total deliveries. you can try

```
  it 'should send an email' do
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count.should == 1
  end
```

also check sender

```
it 'renders the sender email' do  
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first.from.should == ['notifications@domain.com']
end
```

Also check subject line

```
it 'should set the subject to the correct subject' do
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first.subject.should == 'Here Is Your Story!'
end
```

Comment: Please check my update post how you can test in rspec

Comment: and everytime i do " visit 'some route' it says unidentified method visit

Comment: for route checking https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/routing-specs/named-routes

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher also this

Comment: on checking the subect it says "undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I think your case do not deliveres any mail so `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first` is nil

Comment: what do u mean by that my case do not delive mail ? and how will i solve it

Comment: you have to http://blog.lucascaton.com.br/index.php/2010/10/25/how-to-test-mailers-in-rails-3-with-rspec/ follow to send mail testing by rspec

Comment: i don't have a mailer_spec that was u was saying right ?

Answer (score 0):

The problems you're having will most likely be fixed by writing better tests. 
Here's generally how you would write tests for something like this.

Lets suppose in your routes file you have a post route that looks something like this

```
# config/routes.rb
post "/user/:id/reset_password", to: "users#reset_password"
```

And your User controller looks something like this

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController
  ...
  def reset_password
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.reset_password!
    SomeMailClass.email_reset_instructions(user)
  end
end
```

and your User.rb model looks something like this

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def reset_password!
    update!(password: nil) # or whatever way you want/need to reset the password
  end
end
```

and you have some type of mailing class to send your email

```
# app/models/some_mail_class.rb
class SomeMailClass
  def self.email_reset_instructions(user)
    # do something to send email...
  end
end
```

---

**The way you would go about testing this in the controller would be**

```
# spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  it "#reset_password" do
    user_id = double(:user_id)
    user = double(:user)
    expect(User).to receive(:find).with(user_id).and_return(user)
    expect(user).to receive(:reset_password!).and_return(true)
    expect(SomeMailClass).to receive(:email_reset_instructions).with(user)
    post :reset_password, id: user_id
  end
end
```

**But you shouldn't stop there. Because the implementation of the newly made method `reset_password!` and the `SomeMailClass` has yet to be tested. So you would write model/unit tests like this for them**

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

describe User do
  it ".reset_password!" do
    user = User.create(password: "foo")
    expect(user.password).to eq "foo"
    user.reset_password!
    expect(user.password).to eq nil
  end
end
```

***Then you might install `vcr` and `factory_girl` gems and use them like so to test your mailer***

```
# spec/models/some_mail_class_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

describe SomeMailClass do
  VCR.use_cassette "email_reset_instructions" do |cassette|
    it ".email_reset_instructions" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      SomeMailClass.email_reset_instructions(user)
      # you can write some expectations on the cassette obj to test. 
      # or you can write whatever expectations you need/desire
    end
  end
end
```

And in the end if there was something happening on the front end that a user would click that made this post request you would write a feature test for it as well.

Hope this helps!